# php mysql_query with variable as query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP/MySQL and am not able to get the query to work.

When I do this it works:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_info;");
```

However, when I make a variable called query and pass it into the function, the query does not work. Does anyone know why this could be? (I need to do some processing on the string; that's why I need to make it a variable and then pass it into the function)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM site_info;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: don't use `mysql_*` family. You should use `mysqli_*` or PDO. PDO is preferred way

Comment: That aside, are you getting a specific error?  You probably don't need the semicolon inside the query, but that' unrelated.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that it says `msyql` instead of `mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

`$result = msyql_query($query);` should read `$result = mysql_query($query);`

What 'processing' are you doing on the string? Can you post this?

Also, as @riwette said, you should be using `mysqli_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). There are many benefits over using the `mysql` functions; it'll do you good to take a look.

To answer your question, this should work fine:

```
$query = "SELECT * from site_info";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code:

`msyql_query` != `mysql_query`

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem: `FROM site_info; ";"`.

Do not put `";"` inside the query unless it part of data you are retrieving.

Also I heard that `mysql_*` is about to be depreciated so you need to get a hand of PDO or `mysqli_*` or better yet use a PHP Framework.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_info");
```